# Sending email in Emacs programs

Tags: email, emacs, elisp

Is there a way to build up an email message from a region or buffer, set up a recipient and then send a message in elisp code?

I've configured emacs to send mail via my [gmail account](http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009/02/sending-mail-with-emacs-in-windows.html)  and I'd like to be able to send myself emails from elisp programs. The command used is message-mail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a wrapper for message-mail that prompts you for the 'to' and 'subject' lines:

```
(defun my-message-mail-region (b e to subject)
  "Send the current region in an email"
  (interactive "r\nsRecipient: \nsSubject: ")
  (let ((orig-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (message-mail to subject)
    (message-goto-body)
    (insert (save-excursion (set-buffer orig-buffer)
                            (buffer-substring-no-properties b e)))
    (message-send-and-exit)))
```

Comment: Mm it is worth mentioning that this will ask you for a sending method, then automatically set the (custom) variable "message-send-mail-function" to your choice.

Comment: I'm getting an error message that says: 

    `In mail-region: init.el:48:3:Warning: Use 'with-current-buffer' rather than save-excursion+set-buffer`